# Problema firebase is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

estoy teniendo un problema en la siguiente funcion:

```
function observer() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
     
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
      var uid = user.uid;
      console.log("Logged");
      // ...
    } else {
      // User is signed out
      // ...
    }
  });


}
```

El problema en cuestion es el siguiente:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lei varios post donde lo que hacian era poner links de firebase o cambiar unos parametros en la consola de firebase, pero no es mi solucion, por eso abro otro post,

Estos son mis link de firebase:

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/8.2.1/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.6.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "-",
    authDomain: "-",
    projectId: "-",
    storageBucket: "-",
    messagingSenderId: "-",
    appId: "-",
    measurementId: "-"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0g9F.png
```

*Censuro los parametros de configuracion*

No se si alguien sabe como solucionarlo me ayudaria mucho.

Muchas gracias de antemano,
Saludos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que los scripts se importan según el orden en el que los pones, por ejemplo; si importas una librería después de importar el script que usa esa librería, es lógico que te va a reportar un error.

La solución en tu caso es simple, solo pon el script que depende de firebase después de todos los otros scripts:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/8.2.1/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.6.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "-",
    authDomain: "-",
    projectId: "-",
    storageBucket: "-",
    messagingSenderId: "-",
    appId: "-",
    measurementId: "-"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

Además de esto, te recomiendo mucho que pongas todos los scripts al final de la etiqueta body, para que javascript pueda leer totalmente el DOM.

Comment: Anythingg, ya lo movi hacia arriba pero el problema no se me soluciona, que puedo hacer_

Comment: Si accedes a la consola del sitio y pones firebase te retorna undefined o null?

Comment: Te subire lo que me retorna al post

Comment: Ahi te subi al post lo que me retorna la consola cuando escribo firebase

Comment: El link de firebase-ui puede que esté roto, ya que reporta un error al tratar de obtenerlo

Comment: Acabo de entrar al link que pusiste para tratar de obtener firebase-ui. En efecto, está roto ya que retorna un 404, el archivo no existe en el link que estás tratando de obtener

Comment: Lo elimine y el codigo parece funcionar bien, pero el bendito problema es que no puedo utilizar el observer

Comment: También entré a la documentación de firebase en google, si reemplazas el link de firebase-ui que tienes actualmente por https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.6.1/firebase-ui-auth.js te funciona?

Comment: Realmente lo necesito, es muy molesto estar programando funciones cuando el usuario este logeado y cada vez que se haga un cambio tener que logearse

Comment: me entra a un link con muchas lineas de codigo, asi que supongo que si me funciona

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/8.2.1/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.6.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<script>
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "-",
    authDomain: "-",
    projectId: "-",
    storageBucket: "-",
    messagingSenderId: "-",
    appId: "-",
    measurementId: "-"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

La diferencia con tu código es el orden. Ahora firebase-auth.js está antes de tu script.

Comment: ordene el codigo pero no se me soluciono, que otra cosa puedo hacer?

Comment: 2 cosas: Dejar la pregunta original tal cual estaba y aceptar cualquier de las 2 respuestas que te hemos dado, ambas son exactamentelo mismo: ordenar código que solucionó tu escenario original. Luego crear una nueva pregunta con tu nuevo escenario que es diferente de la pregunta original, con esto mantienes el orden en el sitio y evitas las N actualizaciones por cada pequeño avance en tu proyecto